# Como fazer um upload usando o php sem formulários

Tags: php, upload, symfony-2, libcurl

Preciso fazer um upload de um arquivo do servidor local para outro servidor. 
Nesse ambiente eu compacto o arquivo no servidor local e envio o arquivo compactado para o servidor remoto. 
O servidor remoto vai ter as regras especificações de validação para saber se aceita o arquivo ou não e etc... Seria possível eu enviar um arquivo que está em /tmp/test.tar.gz para o servidor remoto? se sim, como eu faria para enviar o arquivo nessa requisição (no servidor local) e receber do outro lado (no servidor remoto)?

o uso do file_get_content, nesse caso acho que seria inviável pois o arquivo poderia ser grande, e creio que ao ser carregado na memória do servidor acabaria gerando um alto consumo de recursos.

A ideia seria ter algo simples como o  do http.

Eu comecei tentando usar o CURL, mas no caso do [curl](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/) estou tendo problemas para o servidor remoto reconhecer os parâmetros que estou enviando por get.

```
Class System{
    public static function getContentURI($uri, array $post = array(), $header = array())     {
        if (empty($uri)) {
            return false;
        }
        //Initialise the cURL var
        $ch = curl_init($uri);

        //Get the response from cURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        if (!empty($post)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        }
        if (!empty($header)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        }
        // Execute the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            throw new \Exception($response . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
    public static function parseFileToParamContentURI($file, $field) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Recupera o nome do arquivo
        $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Recupera o mime-type
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);

        //Create a POST array with the file in it
        $dataFile = array(
            $field => '@' . $file
            . ';filename=' . $filename
            . ';type=' . $mime,
        );

        return $dataFile;
    }
}
```

O código que estou usando para fazer o envio é:

```
// Servidor que deveria receber o upload
$uri = 'http://127.0.0.1' . $this->get('router')->generate('receive_log') . '?' . http_build_query(array('chave' => <teste>));
// Formata o arquivo no formato que possa ser enviado
$params = System::parseFileToParamContentURI('/tmp/test', 'file');
// Requisição CURL
$resp = System::getContentURI($uri, $params);
```

Com o curl eu não estou conseguindo receber os parâmetros que passo por get no servidor, as funções que usavam o curl eu troquei pelo comando [redirect](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) do Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

achei a leitura do arquivo desnecessária, aqui um simples exemplo.
de uma ajustada em seu código, isso deve funcionar.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES) || !empty($_POST)){
    var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);
    die;
}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/test/curl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'file' => "@".realpath('curl.php'), //arquivo, o @ le e envia o arquivo
        'input_qualquer' => 'olaaaa'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

mas no seu caso o problema deve estar em:

faltou

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

e ajustar o array

```
        //Create a POST array with the file in it
    $dataFile = array(
        'field' => '@' . realpath($file),
        'filename' => $filename,
        'type' => $mime,
    );
```